# Definition of class member

Tags: c++, class

We can declare a class member like this:

```
class Test {
public:
    int a;
}
```

this is the how we declare, but I want to know where the variable `a` is defined.

I know the static class member, it is the static variable so it can't be defined in the class, it should be defined outside the class. So I think the normal class member should have a place to be defined, I guess it's the constructor where the normal member is defined implicitly. Is that right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For non-static data members, the declaration and definition are one and the same.

> So I think the normal class member should have a place to be defined, I guess it's the constructor where the normal member is defined implicitly.

I think I can see where you're coming from.  For each static data members, there is only one variable instance per type (for templates - each template instantiation creates a distinct type) - and that's why the declaration is more like an extern declaration for normal variables - it's saying "this variable will have an address somewhere - ask the linker to stitch in the address later".  The *definition* is where the program asks the compiler to reserve actual memory for the variable in that specific translation unit's object, which will be found by the linker and made accessible to the code in other translation units that knew of and access the variable based on the declaration.  (It's a little more complicated for templates).  So, loosely speaking and from a programmer perspective, the static data member definition appears to be the line of source code triggering the allocation of memory and arranging for the constructor to run.  Once you've written the definition, allocation and construction are all sorted.

For non-static data members it's quite different though - when the class definition is parsed by the compiler there's still no actual request for those non-static data members to be given any memory anywhere, as there's not yet an instance object of that class type.  Only when some other code indicates the need for an object instance will the compiler need to arrange memory (if not using placement `new`) and construction.  Put another way, for non-static data-members definition and allocation/construction are generally decoupled - with separate source code.

This all applied recursively: when an object instance is itself static or of file/namespace scope, the memory and construction (including of the data members inside the class) will be arranged (not necessarily performed) when the definition is seen, as above.  But very often object instances are on the stack or heap.  Either way the allocation and construction code for the data members is driven by the way the containing object is created, and is unrelated to the data member's definition.

Answer (score 0):

Every instance of an object is given some reserved space in memory for that object. Possibly in heap storage or on the stack.

It's at a specific location within that space that every member variable of that object is stored.

Answer (score 0):

`a` could be defined right after the declaration, in the constructor, or completely outside of the class. Here is an example showing all the ways that `a` can be defined

```
class Test {
public:
    int a = 5;
    Test() {
        a = 5;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test foo;
    foo.a = 5;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a good practice, you should encapsulate your data members and manage their definitions in specific methods like SetA(), GetA(), and you can give default values in the constructor